# Zip list of observables into another Zip observable RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2, rxandroidble, rxbluetooth

I am trying to `zip` the list of `zip` `Observables` but the issue is I am only getting the same values from the zipped observables every time. The reason why I am doing this is to perform two operations `1st reading index` and `2nd reading data` from ble for a certain number of times -in following example it is 6 time.

Not sure how to handle this with `RxJava2`

here is the code snippet

```
 private Observable<Pair<byte[],byte[]>> getValueFromIndication(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection){

         final PublishSubject<Boolean> unsubscribeSubject = PublishSubject.create();


        return Observable.zip(

                rxBleConnection.setupIndication(Data.INDEX,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it).takeUntil(unsubscribeSubject),
                rxBleConnection.setupIndication(Data.DATA,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it).takeUntil(unsubscribeSubject),

                (bytes, bytes2) -> {

                    unsubscribeSubject.onNext(true);

                    return Pair.create(bytes,bytes2);
                }
        );
}
```

from my main stream i am first creating the list of `Observables` and zip it and pass it

```
 .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> {


        List<Observable<Pair<byte[],byte[]>>> observableList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

            //Creating list of observables so that 6 times this function gets fire
            observableList.add(getValueFromIndication(rxBleConnection));

        }

        // Zipping Zipped list of observables 
        return Observable.zip(observableList,Data::OperationReadings);
    }).subscribe(bytes->{


    })
```

Here, I always get the same values in `Data::OperationReadings`. Currently, I am getting the following data which I don't want.

*each time same index and value*

```
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
```

The expected data is as follows

*each time different index and value*

```
INDEX [1] DATA [10,30,20,30,33,0]
INDEX [2] DATA [11,11,2,0,3,0]
INDEX [3] DATA [0,0,0,0,33,0]
INDEX [4] DATA [10,30,0,30,3,0]
INDEX [5] DATA [10,0,0,30,3,0]
INDEX [6] DATA [10,0,20,30,3,9]
```

Comment: Does each index to be emitted needs a separate turning on of the indication? Or can the indication be persisted till all 6 indications are received?

Comment: emission needs separate turning on and of indication. On -> read->off , On->read->Off and so on. Each time new index and data is emitted from ble device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the same data repeated 6 times is that you subscribe to individual `getValueFromIndication()` at the same time. Effectively every Observable run in parallel. You want to run each subscription in sequence. The solution could be to replace this:

```java
        return Observable.zip(observableList,Data::OperationReadings);
```

with:

```java
        return Observable.concat(observableList) // we want to subscribe each Observable from list after the previous one will complete
            .toList() // we want to gather all results from individual Observables from the list — this returns a Single
            .toObservable() // get back to the Observable class so the types will match
            .map(Data::OperationReadings); // we map it into the OperationReadings class
```

Comment: In case any list item in observableList causes any error then does that propagates to the ultimate subscriber's onError?

Comment: Yes. It should propagate to the subscriber's onError. To prevent that there would need to be an explicit handling of errors added into the chain.